# jQuery end(), where exactly it is useful

Tags: jquery, business-logic, jquery-end

I have looked in to the jquery documentation of function end(),

definition : End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

i have understood the functionality, but i could not able to make out, where it is more helpful.

ex:

```
<p>text</p>
<p class="middle">Middle <span>text</span></p>
<p>text</p>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').length); //alerts 1
alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').end().length); //alerts 3
alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').find('span')
</script>
```

i have understood the second line displaying `//alerts 3` , but it can also be written as

```
 alert(jQuery('p').length); //alerts 3
```

Then why extra two methods `.filter` and `.end()` ,

please give me an example, where the .end() will be useful.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? It provides you with examples.

Comment: @Blender, dude i have looked and understood the use, but as i said, for me it looks not that important

Comment: take as case `<p class="middle"><span class="i1">Middle</span> <span class="i2">text</span></p>` then $('p').filter('.middle').find('.i1').css('color', 'red').end().find('.i2').css('color', 'green')` http://plnkr.co/edit/tNWZM5lbWHiqjqQkJ7Yj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<p>text</p>
<p class="middle">Middle <span>text</span></p>
<p>text</p>
```

in this p tag  as sibling element

and pwith class "middle" has child tag  which is "span" tag

now talk about your **js**

```
     <script type="text/JavaScript">

        /*it display 1 and its right first we find p tag then in this we filter by "middle class" 
        and in p tag only one have this class so alert  1
       */
 alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').length); 

       /*it display 3 and its right first we find p tag then in this we filter by "middle class" then again use end inn jquery then it again goes to previous selector means  
    (jQuery('p').filter('.middle') to jQuery('p') 

    so it alert 3
                  */
 alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').end().length); //alerts 3

    /*it display 3 and its right first we find p tag then in this we filter by "middle class" then again use find span and it has one span in middle class so it alert 1

   */ 
        alert(jQuery('p').filter('.middle').find('span').length); alert 1
        </script>
```

reference [end](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)